# Windows Azure VM SSL and Cloudapp.net

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl, iis-7, virtual-machine

I installed an ASP.net application on a windows Azure VM (IIS 7). SSL certificate is installed, configured and the application works correctly. I have removed Http binding and http endpoints.

The issue I am having is that if I use the cloudapp.net link (using https), the application still opens with a mismatched certificate.

What can I do to deny any user from opening my application using https://xx.cloudapp.net/x?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. unfortunately this type of question isn't suited for this community as it isn't as such about programming. You should try another Stack exchange Network site like serverfault...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really silly that people are saying this isn't the right place for this question, since some of the solutions could be code related. ie: In your application, check the host and if it's cloudapp.net, do a URL redirect.

There's a few different options here but it sounds like what you're looking for is just the ability to prevent someone from viewing the application using that URL.

What I would do is set up a site in IIS that uses Host Header resolution to look for xx.cloudapp.net. If that URL is recognized, do a redirect using the HTTP redirect settings to the https version of your app. Don't bind the SSL port to this site or you'll run into SSL errors like you showed above.

The other option is to leave it out entirely and simply use the Host Header resolution to filter out requests for your site. I suspect what you've done is assign all incoming requests to the only IP address on the system, which is why the xx.cloudapp.net is showing your app and the cert is failing.

This would cause xx.cloudapp.net to fail to show any site at all but I think that might be what you want to do anyway.